# how to protect my token of API when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

I have one application on Heroku that will use Tweepy to access Tweet data. Usually, what I do is to git push to the github and since Heroku is linked with it, the app will be automatically updated.  It will be stupid to push the script with the token to Github. I know people usually use another py file to store the key. But when you deploy an app online, you will also need to push that py file which does not solve the problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [environnements variables of Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Then, in your code, your can access to this with:

`MY_TOKEN = os.environ['MY_TOKEN']`